# Why can't Jesus periodically visit Earth?

Tags: life-of-jesus, gospel-of-matthew

> “But concerning that day and hour no one knows, not even the angels of heaven, nor the Son, but the Father only.

[Matthew 24:36](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2024:36&version=ESV)

---

The Gospel of Matthew tells us that Jesus will return *someday*. All Christians yearn for his return.

But why is Jesus scheduled to return *only* once at some indefinite time in the future?

Why can't He periodically visit Earth?

Is he "busy" visiting other planets? Does he need to do "chores" in Heaven?

Comment: I put the words 'busy' and 'chores' in quotes because these are mere metaphors.

Comment: Heaven has a big front lawn and pops wont let him leave until he had mowed all of it.

Comment: Whose to say [He doesn't?](http://www.thedivinemercy.org/) Lots of the Saints have seen Him.  And Catholics certainly believe we see Him in the Eucharist.

Comment: 'Doesn't' isn't the same as 'can't'. And Jesus return will be a coming to take up his kingship and rule the Earth. It will be a time of decision and judgement for all people. That's not the sort of thing that happens 'occasionally'. You are rather suggesting by your tone that you are not taking the question seriously.

Comment: @DJClayworth: On the contrary - There have been many times during the course of human history where a visit would have made a huge difference. During The Black Death, during World War II, after the 2008 Sichuan Earthquake, and after 9/11 are just a few times that come to mind.

Comment: That's the whole "why doesn't God intervene?" question, which is separate, old and widely discussed, including on this site.

Comment: @DJClayworth: No. It's not that broad. Here's what I'm asking: The Gospel of Matthew specifies exactly one return trip for Jesus. My question: Why is it limited to one?

Comment: There are many who believe Jesus *did* periodically visit earth prior to his birth.  I don't know if that really relates to your question though. I've never heard of any orthodox Christian groups claiming he periodically returns post-ascension.

Comment: @PeterTurner is right. *Many* people have seen him in dreams, visions, or in real life such as [this man](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-L1KIU7lao) who converted to Christianity in a prison cell after seeing him. Paul saw him as well after he ascended to heaven.

Comment: For those of you saying that He has visited, I think you are missing the implications of this question. The question is why doesn't he return to Earth physically.

Answer (score 0):

John 16:

> 7 But very truly I tell you, it is for your good that I am going away. Unless I go away, the Advocate will not come to you; but if I go, I will send him to you.

I have heard it said that Jesus going away physically allows for God to be spiritually with everyone.  One can imagine the "scandal" if Jesus were only to visit a few people in bodily form, once in a while. Wouldn't it be a bummer if your spouse said, "Jesus stopped by before you got home from work and gave me a big hug: I really needed it."

Comment: I think that verse may be a good start. I'm not sure I buy the 'scandal' argument, though. And it's also personal conjecture, so probably doesn't really belong in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

He surely could if He wanted to. Yet God in His omniscience has ordained it to be this way for our benefit. `John 16:7`

Besides, faith wouldn't be required if Jesus appeared in bodily form frequently. Yet it is impossible to please God without faith. `Hebrews 11:6`